# how to rotate a sphere around centre (x y z)

Tags: c++, sphere, rotate

I have centre of sphere at x y z. now I want to rotate any point (a b c) on the sphere about centre. how can I do it in c++.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first translate the center of the sphere to the origin, then rotate it, then translate it back to its original position. You can do all 3 of those by constructing a single matrix.

The [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html) library has several classes that make this easy to do, and it has reasonably good documentation. If you're using OpenGL, it's very similar to glsl's data types.

You could do something like this:

```
glm::mat4 transform = glm::mat4(1.0);
transform = translate(transform, glm::vec3(-center.x, -center.y, -center.z));
transform = rotate(transform, angle, glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)); // Assumes up is y-direction
transform = translate(transform, glm::vec3(center.x, center.y, center.z));
```

Then pass each vertex or coordinate of your sphere model through the `transform` matrix, like so:

```
rotatedVertex = transform * vertex;
```

If you're using OpenGL, you can use the matrix as your modelView matrix for the sphere, for example.